# Learning the expressive power of Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have lots of functions of the following template:

```
function (field, filter){
  var q = {};
  q[field] = doSomething(filter);
  return q;
}
```

I am new to Javascript, but already got the idea that it is a very expressive language. So, my question is can the body of such a function be written more concisely?

(I cannot pass `q` as the parameter and eliminate `var q = {}`, since the output of these functions should not be merged into a single object hash).

I am perfectly aware that knowing the answer to this question is likely to make my code neither faster nor clearer. I just want to learn, that's all - so no flames, please.

Comment: This might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is not a codereview. I am not seeking to improve the code or verify it correctness. I am seeking to learn the language better.

Comment: I question the need for this function. You are just returning an object with a field set to a value; would it not be clearer to write (from the calling code) `{field: doSomething(filter)}` than to call this function?

Comment: Note that you generally name your function. This probably should be "function f(field...".

Comment: @dystroy anonymous functions are often used as callbacks. These don't need a name.

Comment: Then you must assign it or call it.

Comment: @tucuxi The OP wants to use the value of the variable `field` as the property name. Your example uses uses the literal string "field" as the name.

Comment: @apsillers, if the calling code calls it with a literal fieldValue, then my comment still stands (just use the fieldValue in your initialization). Otherwise, I believe Fozi's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't simplify it more.

You are trying to do something like this:

```
({})[field] = value;
```

but then you want to return the (now modified) `{}`. In order to do that you have to keep a reference to it. That's what your `var q = {}` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can always avoid repetition in your code, using something like

```
function objectWith(field, value) {
   var q = {}; q[field] = value; return q;
}
```

Which would make your original code into

```
function f(field, filter) { 
   return objectWith(field, doSomething(filter); 
}
```

Or even better, avoid 'f' altogether and use

```
var o = objectWith(field, doSomething(filter);
```

whenever you would originally use it, assuming field is always a variable. Were it a literal, it would be even clearer to write

```
var o = { fieldLiteral: doSomething(filter) };
```

Comment: There are no literals here. Other than that, your suggestions are valid, except that each function has a different `doSomething` and all the purpose of the function is encapsulate this different `doSomething`. So, the function is here to stay.

Comment: Ah, but then why not make the doSomething into a function rather than using your current doSomethingAndPutItIntoThisField()? The less a method needs to know of where it is being used, the better!

Answer (score 0):

Just my devious tidbit, but what you are doing is the equivalent as the following piece of code :

```
function f(field, filter){
    var q = {};
    q.__defineGetter__(field, doSomething(filter));
    return q;
}
```

There might be some way to shorten it in that form.